# How to calculate daily and weekly over-time hours in a data-frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is a tough question. I have a data-frame that looks something like this:

```
    Employee    Date    Hours1  Reg      OT 
0    emp1   08/12/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
1    emp1   08/13/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
2    emp1   08/14/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
3    emp1   08/15/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
4    emp1   08/17/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
5    emp2   08/12/2018  7.00    7.00    0.00    
6    emp2   08/13/2018  9.00    8.00    1.00
7    emp2   08/15/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
8    emp2   08/17/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
9    emp2   08/18/2018  8.00    8.00    0.00
```

What I am trying to do is calculate over-time for employees in California. California law says anything over 8 hours in a single day ***and/or*** anything over 40 hours in a single week is considered over-time.

`Hours1` = total hours worked that day.

`Reg = np.where((df['Hours1']) < 8, df['Hours1'], (df['OT']))` (Regular time hours)

`OT = np.where((df['Hours1']) > 8, (df['Hours1']) - 8, (df['OT']))` (OT hours)

The issue occurs when an employee works over 40 hours in a week and has worked over 8 hours in a single day. I am having a hard time combining the two formulas. As you can see, `emp1` worked 40 hours in the first 4 days, so all hours in `row=4` should be considered overtime.

For each date, I would like to add up all the hours under `Hours1`, *for each employee*, and when the amount >=40 then all subsequent hours are considered OT and, for that employee, no hours should be considered regular any longer. It feels like there should be a loop for each row, for each employee, that contains this expression but everything I have tried has not worked.

Ouput should like like this:

```
    Employee    Date    Hours1  Reg      OT 
0    emp1   08/12/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
1    emp1   08/13/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
2    emp1   08/14/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
3    emp1   08/15/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00    
4    emp1   08/17/2018  10.00   0.00    10.00    
5    emp2   08/12/2018  7.00    7.00    0.00    
6    emp2   08/13/2018  9.00    8.00    1.00
7    emp2   08/15/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
8    emp2   08/17/2018  10.00   8.00    2.00
9    emp2   08/18/2018  8.00    4.00    4.00
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

For future readers the key to the equation was `cumsum`. The final code looked like this (Note: I dropped reg hours):

```
df['Cum hours'] = df.groupby('Employee')['Hours1'].transform('cumsum')

df['Week OT'] = np.where(df['Cum hours'] - df['Hours1'] > 40, 
                      df['Hours1'], 
                      df['Cum hours'] - 40)

df['OT'] = np.where(df['Cum hours'] > 40, 
             df['Week OT'], 
             df['OT'])

df = df.loc[:, ['Employee', 'Date', 'Hours1', 'OT']]
```

Comment: What day of the week do your weeks start on?

Comment: Sundays. The days have been removed from this data-frame but I can easily reinsert them if needed.

Comment: "all hours in row=4 should be considered overtime" -- Are you sure this is what you want to do? It sounds like you are double-counting overtime. e.g. for emp1, the overtime sums to 10 hours, which is correct whether it is examined on a weekly basis (50 - 40 = 10) or a daily basis (10 - 8 = 2, for each of 5 days).

Comment: That is how CA calculates over-time. Once you reach 40 hours in a week, everything is considered over-time. Am i missing something?

Comment: @6seven8 Are you trying to calculate total overtime or to classify hours as overtime/regular?

Comment: I take that back. It would have to be regular and OT hours

Comment: So if you work 8 hours a day for 5 days, then (in total) 18 hours of it is counted as overtime? That seems unlikely. I think the overtime in this case should add up to 10 hours.

Comment: 8 hours in a day for 5 days would be 8 hours overtime. but if you work 15 hours for 3 days it would be 24 regular hours and 21 OT hours.

Comment: @Stuart My guess is that OP is trying to classify hours within a day as being regular or overtime per CA regulations.

Comment: I hope I have not been calculating reg/OT wrong. I am going to take another look at OT hours in CA and I will get back.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "if you work 10 hours a day..." but I think you got my point

Comment: Yeah, so this stands... `8 hours in a day for 5 days would be 8 hours overtime, but if you work 15 hours for 3 days it would be 24 regular hours and 21 OT hours and any subsequent hours would be OT`

Comment: @Stuart In particular, if you start on Monday, work for 40 hours straight, and stop for the week, you've worked 16 regular hours and 24 overtime. Which is weird, is that what you are trying to do, OP?

Comment: Yes, well, I actually think it would be 8 hours reg, and the rest OT because you never stopped working.. It is weird but that is CA law :)

Comment: If you have to punch out then punch in again to start another day, yes. Otherwise, wouldn't it reset at midnight or something?

Comment: In CA, you don't punch out if you continue working. And if I wanted to be exact - anything over 12 hours is considered double-time I believe. (or at least this is how I understand it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe only contains data from a single week, do:

```
cumulative_hours = df.groupby('Employee')['Hours1'].cumsum()

ot_within_day = df.OT
ot_within_week = np.where(cumulative_hours - df.Hours1 > 40, 
                          df.Hours1, 
                          cumulative_hours - 40)

ot_CA = np.where(cumulative_hours > 40, 
                 ot_within_week, 
                 ot_within_day)
```

Comment: For future readers: this worked as poster made cumulative hours by grouping by `.groupby` `Employee` as well as by `Hours1` using the `.transform()` method with the `'cumsum'` attribute. Please correct my language if it is wrong and I will edit.

Comment: Why `.transform('cumsum')`? [`.cumsum()` also exists as it own function.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

Comment: @jorijnsmit +1, didn't know it works with groupby's. I'll update my answer, I like this better.